# style binding by @click - vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am toggling one element and at that time, want to bind style another element. But I didn't understand how to achieve this with `@click`

```
data(){
    return {
        show:false,
        filterStyle: {
            top: 0,
            background: "#dfe4ea",
            marginTop: "15px",
            marginBottom: "15px",
        },
    }
}

methods: {
    closing(){
        this.show = !this.show
    },
}

<p class="closeMap" @click="closing()">close</p>
```

**closing div below.**

```
<div v-show="!show"></>
```

**changing styles div below.**

```
<div :style="filterStyle" class="filter"></div>
```

Is there someone can explain it to me?

Edit: By the way, as you see I am binding my styles, no problem with that. But not by `@click`... I want to bind those styles by `@click`.

Comment: `@click` is a hook, allowing you to run code (which can do anything, really) when the user clicks. Which means you can change a property in `vm` which results in a different style applied to the clicked element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if you want to add style on `show` or `!show`, anyway you can achieve it in this way:

```
<div :style="show ? filterStyle : null" class="filter"></div>
```

`filterStyle` will be applied only when `show` is `true`

Comment: I would do it the same way, but I think this would be a slightly more 'readable' way of doing it if you will:

 ```<div :class="{ 'filter': !show, 'filterStyle': show }" ></div>```

Comment: @riesa `filterStyle` is not a class, and I think he wants to keep the `filter` class on the element in both cases (`show` and `!show`). For sure this is something that can be achieved in a better way using different classes

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could make a computed property, which changes based on `this.show`:

```
// Template
<div :style="filterStyle" class="filter"></div>

// Computed property
computed: {
  filterStyle() {
    if (this.show) {
       return {
         top: 0,
         background: '#dfe4ea',
         marginTop: '15px',
         marginBottom: '15px'
       };
    } else {
      return '';
    }
  }
}
```

You could also set `filterStyle` to something else in the click function

Comment: How to combine it with the style in the `<style>` tag?