# adding @click event to bootstrap4 dropdown in nuxtjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu

I have this bootstrap 4 dropdown ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dfg8tbr7/1/)) where I want to change its button's background color @click. But when I add the click event it no longer hides the dropdown menu. This is my code:

```
//template
<div class="dropdown" :class="{ test: test }">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" @click="testing">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</div>

//script
  methods: {
    testing(){
      this.test = !this.test
    }
  }
// css
.isTest{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

What is wrong my code? And also how can I change background color of my dropdown button without breaking its original functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've corrected your code in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/doscLq6b/) fiddle. The solution I have used is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56439880/style-binding-by-click-vue-js) post. Basically, the style you included in your question was never used. What you could do is bind a custom style(`:style="test ? clickedBtn : null"`) in the button tag and use the code below. So in [this](https://jsfiddle.net/doscLq6b/) case `clickedBtn` will only be applied whenever `test` is true.

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    test: false,
    clickedBtn: {
      background: "blue",
      color: "white"  
    }
  },
  methods: {
    testing(){
        this.test = !this.test
      console.log('hasan')
    }
  }
})
```

I'll leave the answer above, but in case that you want to only modify style for when the button is on focus or when the dropdown is shown, customize or override the bootstrap's default style. You can paste the following CSS code into your stylesheet. See the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/g1woqbsr/2/).

```
.myBtn:focus{
  background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: So now if I click on the button and then click on another part of the page the dropdown menu disappears but the button color remains blue. Is there a way to make it so the button color becomes blue ONLY AND ONLY if the dropdown menu is showing?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by just customizing the button's `focus` modifier. See my edited answer.